# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass an array, and an ID as parameters to my controller function, but it's not working.

I tried multiple time with differents ways, but it's still not working.

**view.blade.php**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('clients.insert_clients', [$campagne->id, 'importData_arr' => $importData_arr, 'id_campagne' => $campagne->id]) }}">
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('clients/importer/{campagne}', 'CampagneController@upload_clients')->name('clients.upload_clients');
```

**CampagneController.php**

```
public function insert_clients($importData_arr, $id_campagne)
```

**The error I get**

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CampagneController::insert_clients(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected
```

Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58112710/too-few-arguments-to-function-app-http-controllers-1-passed-and-exactly-2-expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to achieve you goal in a very messy way. First of all your route

```php
Route::post('clients/importer/{campagne}', 'CampagneController@upload_clients')
```

You're declaring a single variable `campagne` but in your controller you're declaring the corresponding fuction as

```php
public function insert_clients($importData_arr, $id_campagne)
```

and that's why you're getting the error, you're passing a single variable (`$campagne`), but the controller's method expects two variables (`$importData_arr`, `$id_campagne`).

You should update the method as follow

```php
public function insert_clients($campagne)
```

as well as your form:

```php
<form method="post" action="{{ route('clients.insert_clients', ['campagne' => $campagne->id]) }}">

@foreach($importData_arr as $value)
<input type="hidden" name="importData_arr[]" value="{{ $value }}" />
@endforeach

<!-- Other fields -->
```

After submitting the form, you can recover your data as follows:

```
public function insert_clients($campagne) {
   $importData_arr = request()->get('importData_arr');
}
```

Comment: Got this `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: It's because `$value` is an array. In this case you have to serialize the data or encode it as JSON and decode it in your controller. Otherwise use a different strategy (like save the `$importData_arr` in session)

Comment: Thank you, I explain a little more what I'm doing. I'm importing data with a CSV file, I know how to do it and it's working well. But I made a confirmation page which shows the data you're importing. I sent the data I took in the file to my view, and I want to send it back to te controller if the user confirm the action. I think there is a better way than making a form and sending the variables in it.

Comment: I should see your code... The user can update the imported data? If no, than it's useless to send it back... Just save it in session (or cache), show the data in the view and the controller recovers the data from the session (or cache). If yes, than there are many solutions... but this is not what you were asking for and without seeing your code it's hard to say... So it's better if you create a new question for that.

Answer (score 2):

Change,

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('clients.insert_clients', [$campagne->id, 'importData_arr' => $importData_arr, 'id_campagne' => $campagne->id]) }}">
```

To

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('clients.insert_clients', ['campagne' => $campagne->id, 'importData_arr[]' => $importData_arr]) }}">
```

Change,

```
public function insert_clients($importData_arr, $id_campagne)
```

To,

```
public function insert_clients($campagne, Request $request)
```

You have a required parameter (`campagne`) as defined by your route so you need to pass it explicitly in that array of data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your route with 2 params instead of 1.

```php
Route::post('clients/importer/{importData}/{campagne}', 'CampagneController@upload_clients')->name('clients.upload_clients');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add id in the route url and that is all. ie
At first this was my route "Route::get('group/edit/', [StudenGroupController::class, 'GroupEdit'])->name('group.edit');" and i updated it to "Route::get('group/edit/{id}', [StudenGroupController::class, 'GroupEdit'])->name('group.edit');" by adding {id} in the route url.